# Duplicate content with image CDN

Tags: seo, canonical-url, cdn, nginx, rel-canonical

I'm in a similar situation as this user:
[CDN virtual subdomain causes duplicated content](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61638/cdn-virtual-subdomain-causes-duplicated-content)

However, I have yet to create the CDN.

My question has 2 parts:

**Part 1:**
I think I may have found an issue with the accepted answer in the question above regarding duplicate content with images. You see, Google has stated that they don't look at rel=canonical on images.

As stated here:
https://www.seroundtable.com/google-rel-canonical-for-images-nope-22549.html

So my fear here is that I would have duplicate content with all my images, hosted on the CDN. What can be done to avoid this?

**Part 2:**
On an nginx server, how can I make site-wide canonical links?

Comment: Sorry but there is no need to create another question just because you dislike the answer. We have many ways of bumping old questions and gaining better answers, in additional to 45 other related questions regarding [CDN SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=CDN+SEO+is%3Aquestion). Additionally you can't use canonical links on resources period because Google doesn't consider these pages, duplicate content is URLS, not CSS, JS, IMG, SVG or any other resource. Page A using the same image as Page B does not make the page duplicate unless everything else is duplicate such as the text.

Comment: Site A using same images as Site B does not make either site duplicate, otherwise if this was remotely true Stock Images market wouldn't be turning over 2-3 Billion a year in sales.

Comment: @SimonHayter So, just to clarify, if Google finds `site.com/images/kitten.png` and `cdn.site.com/images/kitten.png` it wont consider it duplicate content?

Comment: In rankings terms? no... Getty, Creative Commons, Public Domain License and even Stock Images would be a dead market otherwise. Unique images can add to page uniqueness but in no way will it damage your rankings if 10 or 1000 of sites use the same image, in fact its pretty common. Text content is what Google cares about in terms of duplicate content, not images unless your mirroring a site with just images ,then yes... don't expect good rankings.

Comment: However... Duplicate images will only rank you lower when searching for images on Google Image Search since who wants to see the same picture repeated 50 times? and no tag will save you from this, but again... duplicate images is the same as duplicate content.

Comment: @SimonHayter Right, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the clarification.